# EXIficient implementation in Python

Tags: python, xml, xsd, exi

I am trying to use EXI in order to encode an XML Message with Python. I've already seen that there is a Java, javascript and c/c++ implementation of EXI but I can't find a Python one. The only one i saw was the following:

https://github.com/salarshad/pyexip

The problem is that when I try to install it i get the following error:

```
gcc: error: exip-0.4.1/bin/lib/libexip.a: No such file or directory
error: command '/usr/bin/gcc' failed with exit code 1
```

Was someone able to work with this library? Is there another way to Transform XML to binary with Python?
Thank you in advance

Answer (score 0):

Note: there is some confusion about the implementations (names).

https://github.com/salarshad/pyexip is a wrapper around EXIP (http://exip.sourceforge.net/), *not* EXIficient.

EXIficient is a Java implementation of the EXI specification and as far as I know there are ways to call Java from Python...